# How to set timer out/interval for onblur validation to finish before button click operation can start?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, blur

I have a text box & a button which performs some desired operation that are time consuming. Ajax calls to the server to be precise. On the onblur event of the textbox I am fetching the name of a person from the data source using the unique identifier which includes opening a transaction to datasource executing the desired command fetching the output and showing up in the text.

On button click I am submitting the update using the similar approach. Now, because ajax call takes some time to post the update & fetch the output. When I am entering the id in the textbox and then clicking the button directly when the focus is on the textbox. The call on the button is executing before the validation happens any ideas how to make the validation happen before the button click submit call?

Here's some pseudo code:

```
@Html.TextBox("myTextbox", null, new { @class = "textbox"})
<button id="btnSubmit"> submit </button>
```

My Ajax Calls on the blur event (validate) looks something like:

```
 $(document).on('blur', '#myTextbox', function () {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) != '') {
            $.ajax({
                async: true,
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Index/ValidateUser",
                data: {
                    CAI: $('#myTextbox').val()
                },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (response) {
                      $('#myTextbox').val(response.username);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My Ajax Calls on the click event (submit) looks something like:

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function() {
   if ($.trim($('#myTextbox').val()) != '') {
      $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Index/Submit",
            data: {
               CAI: $('#myTextbox').val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
               alert(response.successMessage);
            }
         }
      });
    }
});
```

I am not able to understand why the submit operation on button click happens before the validation on blur by immediately clicking on the button without clicking anywhere else  while the textbox is focused. I am assuming if I add some kind of time interval before the ajax call on button click might trigger only after the blur ajax call is done. But if any better solution is available I am open to learn.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you would like the behavior to be. You're sending an ajax request on blur?

Comment: Yes on both events there's an ajax request.

Comment: Right - but what relation do the ajax requests have with each other? Does one depend on the response from the other?

Comment: Yes, so when the validation occurs it fills the textbox with a string containing the username, that text is used in the button click's submit call to store the username into the data source.

Answer (score 0):

So from what i understand from the question, you are validating it onblur of the textbox from the ajax call. And on click of button you want to update it if it is validated. But when you click on the button when the textbox is focused your update call gets executed directly before the validation call.

To ensure that you validate before updating use a variable as flag.
set the flag in the validate ajax call on success

```
$(document).on('blur', '#myTextbox', function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) != '') {
        $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Index/ValidateUser",
            data: {
                CAI: $('#myTextbox').val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (response) {
                  $('#myTextbox').val(response.username);
                  validateFlag = 1
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

check the flag in update ajax call and update only if validated

```
$(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function() {
   if ($.trim($('#myTextbox').val()) != '' && validateFlag == 1) {
      $.ajax({
            async: true,
            type: "POST",
            url: "/Index/Submit",
            data: {
               CAI: $('#myTextbox').val()
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(response) {
               alert(response.successMessage);
            }
         }
      });
    }
});
```

also be sure to unset the flag onchange event of the textbox so that everytime it changes you need to validate again

```
$(document).on('change', '#myTextbox', function () {
     validateFlag = 0
});
```